# How can I aggregate online count for per hour if I only have online and offline event record of device in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

If I have online and offline event record of device.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS connect_log (
 `deviceId` Int64,
 `eventTime` Datetime() ,
 online Int8
 )  ENGINE = MergeTree
 ORDER BY (`deviceId`,`eventTime`);
```

How can I write a MATERIALIZED VIEW that aggregate online device count for per hour.

**The online count is not only the count of online event , it must include all device that is ever online in this hour(the last event is not offline even the last online event is recorded in many days ago or the last offline event is in the this hour)**.

test case

insert1

```
INSERT into connect_log values 
(1,'2020-07-30 10:01:00',1),
(2,'2020-07-30 10:01:0',1),
(3,'2020-07-30 11:01:00',1);
```

result1:

```
............................
2020-07-30 10:00:00| 2
............................
2020-07-30 11:00:00| 3
............................
```

then insert2

```
INSERT into connect_log values 
(1,'2020-07-30 11:51:00',0),
(2,'2020-07-30 12:01:0',0),
(3,'2020-07-30 13:51:00',0);
```

result1:

```
............................
2020-07-30 10:00:00|  2
............................
2020-07-30 11:00:00| 3
............................
2020-07-30 12:00:00| 2
............................
2020-07-30 13:00:00| 1
............................
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW connect_log_hourly_mv
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY tuple()
ORDER BY (hourlyEventTime) 
AS
SELECT  
  toStartOfHour(eventTime) AS hourlyEventTime, 
  uniqExactIfState(deviceId, online = 1) AS onlineDeviceUniqCountState
  /*
  .. other aggregates ..
  */
FROM connect_log
GROUP BY hourlyEventTime;
```

Query to get aggregated result:

```sql
SELECT 
    hourlyEventTime, 
    uniqExactIfMerge(onlineDeviceUniqCountState) onlineDeviceUniqCount
FROM connect_log_hourly_mv
GROUP BY hourlyEventTime
HAVING onlineDeviceUniqCount > 0
ORDER BY hourlyEventTime;
```

---

*UPDATE*

Materialized view calculates the preliminary aggregates (the status of the earliest event in an hour) that used to calculate final result:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW connect_log_hourly_mv
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY tuple()
ORDER BY (hourlyEventTime) 
AS
SELECT  
  toStartOfHour(eventTime) AS hourlyEventTime, 
  deviceId,
  argMinState(online, eventTime) AS firstEventStatusState
FROM connect_log
GROUP BY hourlyEventTime, deviceId;
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT 
  hourlyEventTime, 
  countIf(deviceId, firstEventStatus = 1) AS uniq_count
FROM (
  SELECT 
    hourlyEventTime, 
    deviceId, 
    argMinMerge(firstEventStatusState) firstEventStatus
  FROM connect_log_hourly_mv
  GROUP BY hourlyEventTime, deviceId)
GROUP BY hourlyEventTime
ORDER BY hourlyEventTime
```

Comment: I am sorry,  you may not getting my point,  the count should include all the devices that ever online but not offline at the begining of the hour.

Comment: @xiemeilong i see, look at the updated version of MV

Comment: still not  works as expected， maybe my requirement not directly supported by clickhouse .@vladimir

Comment: @xiemeilong could you describe this case in your question so that I can reproduce it?